# Safe and effective approach to transfer data between server and client with AJAX/PHP/MySQL?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Well I'm new to PHP but thinking about these stuff has really confused me these days.

Here is my question in detail:

First the situtation is that I need to transfer the data between clients and the server. Ajax should be used to present the data at clients' side. At the server side, PHP and MySQL will be used to parse the request, grab the data and then send it back.

Then the problem comes. User data sent from the brower can contain **&, %, ', "** which may damage the formatted POST request or making database attack. Although we can use JS to detect them, the user is still able to send data bypassing the validation, let alone we cannot simply remove them as they may be useful to the user.

So then I checked my weapon library.
At server side, it turns out that I have too many functions to deal with them:
Apart from regular expessions I have

```
htmlspecialchars, htmlspecialchars_decode, addslashes, stripslashes
urlencode, urldecode, mysql_escape_string, mysql_real_escape_string
```

At client side with javascript, I don't have that many but still have:

```
escape, unescape
```

OK. Learning that I have so many weapons is good but...how to choose, combine and use them is really a headache for me.

For example suppose I want to have a product name called:

**'%Hooray%'+&ABC**

Well maybe no product will be named like this in real life but let's use it as an example.

The & mark will break the POST message.
The +  may impact ajax parsing.
Single quotes may allow SQL injection.
The % mark may cause problems but I'm not sure if it will.

But I still want that name exactly the same after sending it to the database and fetching it back,
which means, the name in database can be different but its presentation in the brower should be the same.

Well this question may be a little bit too long but hope somebody could share some good experience: how to deal with user input string using those functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before sending your data via **ajax**, encode them:
Assuming the data is a **javascript array**.
Why an array?
Because if you have a query already (ex. 'name=me&foo=b&ar') how you can solve that 'b&ar' that is clearly a value to **YOU** but 'b' and 'ar' for the javascript engine?

```
for(i in arr)
   { arr[i] = encodeURIComponent(arr[i]); }
```

[This](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp) function replaces all harmful url characters (, / ? : @ & = + $ #) and some more.
Then you can send your query by building up like `arr.join('');`
But i'd use jquery and send the array right after.

On **PHP side** the basic rule you must obey is that you **NEVER** save your data without `mysql_real_escape_string();`

Comment: `encodeURIComponent` is the correct answer for client-side cleanup. However, your suggestion to use `mysql_real_escape_string` suggests the `mysql_` or `mysqli_` functions, which is in my view not a correct **modern** answer. For that, see the excellent suggestion from @jmoreno to use PDO.

Comment: yes PDO is definitely the way, but how an answer having 'PDO' word in it becomes 'excellent' without providing a practical solution instead of theory?

Comment: His suggestion to use PDO is an excellent suggestion because it is modern best practice -- it is correct. He also references several best practice techniques for client side. If your answer also mentioned PDO instead of the outdated `mysql_` functions, it would be excellent too. You both got a +1 from me, so I don't understand why you'd take exception to my praise of the better aspects of the other answer. The question is theoretical, no details given.

Comment: Thank you all. But if that function alone works, why we still need those others?

Comment: there's nothing in 'need'; each function treats a specific issue; the mysql_real_escape_string() just escapes harmful characters on calling and db saving level, the htmlspecialchars() converts to html entities (not needed and definitely not of same weight as the above on security) which is useful on building XML files by-hand (just an example) etc. In conclusion, your weaponry of defeating nasty characters should be encodeURIComponent for JS and the mysql_real_escape_string() for PHP/Mysql. And yes, jump to mysqli or pdo to reduce these problems..

Answer (score 2):

Serverside what you want are [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php), aka parameterized queries, in order to keep your DB safe (avoid SQL injection).

Client side, I would recommend JSON with defined objects and DOM manipulation, not innerText or innerHTML.  The browser will escape everything it needs to in order to do a post.